# Passing value calculated by array.filter always causes render in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that computes which values to pass based on array.filter. The bad thing is even if the elements of the array are the exact same, it causes a new render due to props change every time.

The component relies on values computed from state:

```
        const [targets, setTargets] = useState<Target[]>([]);
```

Here is the element that is re-rendering when I don't want it to.

```
        <Map
          settings={mediumKneeboardMapSettings}
          targets={getTargets(kneeboardGroupSelected?.id)}
        />
```

Here is the callback that filters based on a groupId if it is passed.

```
  const getTargets = useCallback(
    (groupId?: string) => {
      if (!groupId) {
        return targets;
      }
      const groupTargets = targets.filter(target => target.group === groupId);
      return groupTargets;
    },
    [targets]
  );
```

Every time the parent renders - the `Map` component re-renders if an `id` is passed to `getTargets`. It does not re-render if `undefined` is passed. This makes sense to me because if an `undefined` is passed in, it just returns state which is the same array every time.

However, if I pass an `id` Map re-renders because a new array is created from the `filter` method, even if the members of that element are unchanged (every time the same 2 elements are passed for example). This array has the original elements from `targets`. The bad thing is on EVERY render, the `Map` component treats it as if new targets were passed in even though the parameters haven't changed. This is bad because there are effects in `Map` that do extra work when targets change.

**How do I calculate a subset of an array to pass as props, but not have this trigger a change to the child if the elements are the same?**

I was thinking of `useMemo` or something, I need it to remember the input and save the output, the function is pure as long as targets does not change (which causes a new function to be made due to the callback).

Comment: React won't do a physical re-render if the props have not changed.  But it will still call your function,.   And yes, if you have something expensive, you can `useMemo`,  if it's async you could also use `useEffect`, but don't forget to pass the props that cause it to change.  eg. `useMemo(expensiveStuff, [prop1, prop2])`  etc.  ps, when I say props, I also mean props & state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `useMemo()` for this

```
const groupTargets = useMemo(()=>targets.filter(target => target.group === groupId),[targets]);
```

it runs ony when targets change
or in Map.js you can do this

`export default React.memo(Map)` this will shallow compare props and rerender if props change

but `Kent C Dodds` discourages using `useCallback()` `useMemo()` and `React.memo()` `all the time` as cost of performing those operations is more than cost of `rerendering`. refer https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Comment: Thanks, this works for my solution. The problem I have is what if groupId can change a lot or is passed in via a loop (maybe this exists on 100 elements?). It'd be really nice to have useMemo which takes a parameter and gives back a stored value. Is this possible? (Marked accepted, works in my case, thanks!)